# Manual or Automatic Speedlight?

Tags: nikon, flash, hotshoe-flash, ttl

I'm beginner photographer. I thought of buying Speedlight and found cheap Yongnuo 460 for about $35. But it is Manual (No TTL).

1. Is it hard to use Manual flash without TTL ?
2. Should I have to choose TTL flash ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Advantages of TTL over manual mode when using speedlites](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24242/advantages-of-ttl-over-manual-mode-when-using-speedlites)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual and TTL have both pros and cons. Depending on the way you approach photography one might be better suited than the other.

I recommend that you get the "Flash Bus" DVDs at Adorama to help you decide what's best for you. Disc one has David Hobby on manual flash, disc two has Joe McNally on TTL.

My own preference is to work with manual flashes when I'm working in my basement with total control of the light and the environment, but I tend to use TTL when I'm outside with less control of all the light sources.

The manual Yongnuo flashes are awesome, by the way. I have three YN460-II units and I love them. Even if you decide to try TTL in the future, at $35 these are a great buy.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Is it hard to control exposure with Manual flash ?

Comment: I guess that depends, but I wouldn't say it is hard. Try to take a good picture in manual mode with your camera alone and see if you find it hard. If that's hard, then manual flashes will be hard too. If you want to get a decent (but maybe not as great as it could be) picture with minimum effort and in short time, then TTL is the way to go. If you want to get more careful about lighting details and have the time and the opportunity to take several pictures until you arrive at the perfect result then manual flash will work great for you. Good luck.